# common objects in 2 ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have 2 `ArrayList`. And I want elements with common `phone`.

```
ArrayList<Contact> phone_contacts;
ArrayList<Contact> registered_users;
```

I used below method to get common elements:

```
ArrayList<Contact> common_contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>(phone_contacts);
common_contacts.retainAll(registered_users);
```

But, the result I get is empty. How can I get common phone contact in `common_contacts` ArrayList?

**Contact**

```
public class Contact {
    private String name;
    private String phone;

    public Contact(String name, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to override proper equals() and hashcode() implementations in Contact class to make this work. JVM uses equals() implementation to compare two objects are same or not.

Comment: @Nambari: How can I do that? I am new in java.

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073330/the-contains-trap-in-java-collections.html might be good example/

Comment: You can clone array list in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you are treating a phone number as an identifier, I would advise caution. [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Phone Numbers](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md)

With that said...

`retainAll` ultimately uses the `equals` method. Given that you have a custom object (and not something like a String or int that have a defined `equals`), the simplest method would be to define an `equals` method for `Contact` that returns true if the two have the same phone number.

However, that might not be what you are looking for. For example, `equals` might need to check the name in other contexts.

There are a couple other approaches you could take. Since you mentioned Android, Java 8 streams are currently out. An `Iterator` loop might do the job. Collect all of the phone numbers for registered users into a `Set` (so you have the unique list), then start with a `List` of all of your contacts, and remove any that don't have a phone number from that set.

```
Set<String> registeredPhoneNumbers = new HashSet<>();
for (Contact c : registered_users) {
  registeredPhoneNumbers.add(c.getPhone());
}
List<Contact> common_contacts = new ArrayList<>(phone_contacts);
for (Iterator<Contact> iter = common_contacts.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
  Contact c = iter.next();
  if (!registeredPhoneNumbers.contains(c.getPhone())) {
    iter.remove();
  }
}
```

Since you mentioned in comments that there could be a million distinct registered_users, this might be more space-efficient:

```
Set<String> phoneNumbers = new HashSet<>();
for (Contact c : phone_contacts) {
    phoneNumbers.add(c.getPhone());
}

Set<String> overlappingNumbers = new HashSet<>();
for (Contact registered : registered_users) {
    if (phoneNumbers.contains(registered.getPhone())) {
        overlappingNumbers.add(registered.getPhone());
    }
}
List<Contact> common_contacts = new ArrayList<>();
for (Contact contact : phone_contacts) {
    if (overlappingNumbers.contains(contact.getPhone())) {
      common_contacts.add(contact);
    }
  }
}
```

You may want to check the phone number for null as well.

Comment: What is `c` and `iter` in if loop? `if (!registeredPhoneNumbers.contains(c.getPhone())) {
    iter.remove();
  }`

Comment: Thats what I get for writing an Iterator loop when all I do is Java 8 these days. Fixed.

Comment: It's working fine. Thanks! I just have 1 question. Is it efficient method if I have 1 million `registered_users` and hundreds of `phone_contacts`?

Comment: Depends on how you define efficient. Worst case, you have a million distinct phone numbers, so you will have a Set<String> of one million entries, which will take up quite a bit of memory (you did say Android...) The other option would be to build a Set of the unique phone numbers on phone contacts, which would be much smaller, then iterate over registered users, making note of which phone numbers are used - maybe store used ones in another Set. Finally, loop back over the phoneContacts, only keeping those that have a phone number that is being used.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the method [RetainAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) in the List the you will get the common objects between 2 Lists..\

## Example:

consider the lists of integers, (just for the sake of the example) it will work with your class...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5));
    List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(list1);
    list3.retainAll(list2);
    System.out.println("List1:" + list1);
    System.out.println("List2:" + list2);
    System.out.println("List common:" + list3);

    }
```

---

In your case the class contacts needs to be modified so the Method ArrayLst.retainAll() can somehow identify whether a Contact is the same as the other using as criteria the Phone number...

## Modify/Improve the Contact Class by adding the **HashCode** and **Equals**:

but you need to use as criteria only the phone Number

```
public class Contact {
    private String name;
    private int phone;

    public Contact(String name, int phone) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "Contact [name=" + name + ", phone=" + phone + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + phone;
    return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Contact other = (Contact) obj;
    if (phone != other.phone)
        return false;
    return true;
    }

    public int getPhone() {
    return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(int phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

## Implement the List of Contacts and call the method RetainAll

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Contact> list1 = new ArrayList<Contact>(Arrays.asList(new Contact(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), 1),
        new Contact(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), 2), new Contact(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), 3),
        new Contact(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), 4), new Contact(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), 5)));
    List<Contact> list2 = new ArrayList<Contact>(Arrays.asList(new Contact(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), 1),
        new Contact(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), 3), new Contact(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), 5)));
    List<Contact> list3 = new ArrayList<Contact>(list1);
    list3.retainAll(list2);
    System.out.println("List1:" + list1);
    System.out.println("List2:" + list2);
    System.out.println("List common:" + list3);
    }
```

Comment: I need common phone only. Not entire object. Is there any way to modify that?

Comment: Tag says Android, so no.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your Contact class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof Contact &&
            this.name != null && this.name.equals(((Contact)obj).name) &&
            this.phone!= null && this.phone.equals(((Contact)obj).phone);
}
```

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-

See Also: hashCode()